# using isset() on $_POST

Tags: php

When checking if multiple $_POST variables have been set, would the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['day'])){

}
```

be the same as:

```
if(isset($_POST)){

}
```

or would `isset($_POST)` return true if only one $_POST variable has been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `empty`

```
if(empty($_POST['year']) and empty($_POST['month']) and empty($_POST['day'])){
   // Empty
}
else
{
  //Not empty
}
```

but best way to check(my Opinion use OR )

```
if(empty($_POST['year']) || empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['day'])){
   // Empty
}
else
{
  //Not empty
}
```

**Usage of `isset()`**

The isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. If a variable is already unset with unset() function, it will no longer be set. The isset() function return false if testing variable contains a NULL value.

**Usage of `empty()`**

Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

> **if You use `empty()` it will act both of these `if(isset($_POST) && $_POST!=""){`**

Comment: would that be the same as  empty($_POST)  ?

Comment: @SAMTHEMAN999 ya. check its full fill your need

Comment: so i could use:   `if(empty){  }`     instead of    `if(empty($_POST['year']) and empty($_POST['month']) and empty($_POST['day'])){` ?

Comment: ya absolutely. Use **OR** (My Opinion )

Comment: @sam happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST!=""){

}
```

Write this code i hope this is Work